# I need the solution to a Javascript DOM textnode selection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I get all the text nodes in this using javascript?
I've tried so many things but them seam not to be working?

```
 <td bgcolor="#f2f2f2" id='product-1'>
<img src="images/icon.png" width="37" height="30" align="left" style="margin: 8px 10px 25px 0">
<h4 style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold">Heading</h4>
<p>TEXT</p>
 </td>
```

Comment: Do you mean all the text within tags <P> ?

Comment: I mean all the tags.. sorry I don't understand to much about the dom..

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve (e.g. give a sample data and expected result)

Comment: @Matthew so you want to select all these tags with one thing? or do you want individually?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you would want to get all tags ? IF it's getting text/attribute from a particular tag it will be really simple

Comment: @Petre I would want to be able to get all the tags in an array within a div container.

Comment: Yes just getting the text would help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example returns an Array of the text nodes contained by node and its descendents. 
It skips nodes containing only white space

```
function deepText(node){
    var A= [], tem;
    if(node){
        node= node.firstChild;
        while(node!= null){
            if(node.nodeType== 3){
                if(/\S/.test(node.data)) A[A.length]= node;
            }
            else A= A.concat(deepText(node));
            node= node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
//test
var text= [], nodes= deepText(document.getElementById('product-1'));

for(var i= 0, L= nodes.length; i<L; i++){
    // do whatever you want to the node
    var pa= nodes[i].parentNode;
    if(pa.nodeName== 'H4') pa.style.color= 'blue';
    text.push(nodes[i].data);
}
alert(text.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the text, you can do:

```
var el = document.getElementById('product-1');
alert(el.textContent || el.innerText);
```

The above can be turned into a general "getText" function fairly easily.

If you want to get the actual text nodes, you have to look at each DOM element and get its child nodes, then iterate over each child node looking at whether it's an element (node type 1) or text (node type 3).